# Custom maintenance page for Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Having issue with implementing a custom maintenance page in Magento 2. I have followed the suggested config for nginx per [Devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html) and combined it with the sample nginx config that comes with the magento install. For whatever reason the homepage is never redirected to the maintenance page, however all other links seem to redirect properly. Any help is appreciated.